# Why the chef recipe cannot read the values from bash environment variables?

Tags: chef, chef-solo

This is the content of my shell script:

```
export TARGET_ROLE=play
vagrant up
```

I am using the script to export environment variables in order to set some variables inside my chef cookbook

```
role = ENV['TARGET_ROLE']
Chef::Log.info("Using role #{role}")
node.override[:mainapp][:target_role] = role

seq = ENV['SEQ']
Chef::Log.info("Using seq #{seq}")
node.override[:mainapp][:server_seq] = seq
```

Here is what I see in my log:

```
==> default: [2015-09-14T07:22:35+00:00] DEBUG: Found recipe mainapp_common_env in cookbook mainapp
==> default: [2015-09-14T07:22:35+00:00] INFO: Using role 
==> default: [2015-09-14T07:22:35+00:00] INFO: Using seq
```

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set an environment variable on the host. -- But Chef runs inside your Virtualbox VM.

To set environment variables for it use the `binary_env` option as described in the [Vagrant documentation for Chef provisioning](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/chef_common.html).